# PHP Imagick is installed but not displayed in phpinfo and not working

Tags: php, windows, imagick

I installed Imagick in my PHP 8.1 on windows local server with apache 2.4.
When I type "php -i" I can see imagick is installed and enabled. Also in "php -m" I can see it. But imagick is not presented in phpinfo() page so is not working. Imagick dir is added to paths. Where can be a problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do the "Loaded configuration file" and "Additional .ini files parsed" of the `php -i` output and the phpinfo page match? If not, perhaps the Apache module and the CLI binary are not looking at the same configuration.

Comment: @WanderNauta Yes, loaded configuration file is the same (C:\php81\php.ini) and additional ini is "(none)" in both cases.

Comment: Have you restarted the PHP process?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Sure. Apache has been restarted a couple of times. I also tried to add more changes in php.ini (like disable another module) and all other changes are applied in phpinfo webpage.

Comment: Any another ideas?

Comment: I see questions like this about once a week, and although I absolutely believe you when you say you are editing the correct file, I can tell you that almost all of those, after bouncing PHP, respond with an “oops, I was editing the wrong file”. So I would absolutely make sure you are in the correct file. I apologize for asking you to quadruple check what you’ve already told us.

Comment: @ChrisHaas ![Here](http://data.danekpetr.cz/imagick2.jpg) is a screenshot of php -i and phpinfo, where you can see same conf. file.

Comment: @P.Danek, yep, I definitely agree with you, sorry for asking! Have you tried just a magic reboot? That's about all I have otherwise. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had to copy all CORE_ and IM_MOD_ files to the PHP root directory and after this I can see imagick in phpinfo too.